# How do I fix the "Google Cloud SDK component manager is disabled for this installation" error?

Tags: software-installation, 19.04, cloud, google, sdk

I just tried to install the Google Cloud SDK on my Ubuntu 19.04 following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu).

Specifically I did:

```sh
# Create environment variable for correct distribution
CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(grep VERSION_CODENAME /etc/os-release | cut -d '=' -f 2)"

# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Import the Google Cloud Platform public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package list and install the Cloud SDK
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

And then run `gcloud init` and followed the process there.

When I now do `gcloud components update` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) 
You cannot perform this action because the Cloud SDK component manager 
is disabled for this installation.
```

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 17):

As the issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697026/install-google-cloud-components-error-from-gcloud-command), try installing `google-cloud-sdk` from anything other than `apt`. 
1. Remove `google-cloud-sdk` first: 
`sudo apt purge --autoremove google-cloud-sdk` 
2. Then download the correct `.tar.gz` for your system from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux and extract it `tar -xzf google-cloud-sdk-*` to a directory and install it running `sudo ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`.
 Restart the terminal session. `gcloud components update` should work now.

Comment: I did this. But I'm getting the error " Command 'gcloud' not found, but can be installed with:       sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk "

Comment: Thank you for the SO link you shared, I fixed mine by using [another answer on the same link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56314665/1235675) without uninstalling existing SDK - simply extracting the `tar.gz` file and replacing the `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk` directory